# Filter an nsmutable array issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
@interface demodata : NSObject             
{  
   NSString *Day;     
   NSString *content;   
   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Day;  
   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *content;  
}  
-------

Test.m file--  

NSMutableArray *sessions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  
demodata * sess = [[demodata alloc] init];  
sess.Day=@"Monday";  
sess.content=@"HI";  
 [sessions addObject :sess];  
[sess release];  


demodata * sess1 = [[demodata alloc] init];  
sess1.Day=@"Tuesday";  
sess1.content=@"Bye";  
 [sessions addObject :sess1];  
[sess1 release];
```

I tried

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Day == %@", @"Monday"];  
NSArray *filteredArray = [sessions filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

my array object is class(nsobject)..
It's not working...

How to i filter the array(sessions) by daywise..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code working perfectly..The problem is there is some **whitespace** in the array object.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `NSArray`s `-filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` and pass an `NSPredicate` describing your needs.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Day = %@", @"Tuesday"];
NSArray *filteredArray = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: it's not working.my array object is class(nsobject)

Comment: What do you mean? Your example indicates it's an object of type `demodata` which has a property `Day`.

Comment: I implemented the code in another file Test.m